# JSCH sudo su command "tty" error

Tags: sudo, jsch, tty, su

Java - Jsch sudo command.

I am using Jsch and my task is to login to server and run command as following

```
sudo su - bumboo
```

Using following code i am successfully able to connect but when i try to run command it gives me error `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Following is my code

```
public static Channel sudoBamboo(Session session, String sudo_pass) throws Exception {

        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        //SUDO to bamboo user
        String command = "sudo su - bumboo";
        channel.setCommand(command);

        //InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.setInputStream(null, true);

        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        //channel.setErrStream(System.err);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out, true);
        channel.setExtOutputStream(System.err, true);
        //Test change
        //channel.setPty(false);
        channel.connect();

        out.write((sudo_pass + "\n").getBytes());
        out.flush();

        return channel;
    }
```

jsch in sudo.java available example they advised to use

```
// man sudo
      //   -S  The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the
      //       standard input instead of the terminal device.
      //   -p  The -p (prompt) option allows you to override the default
      //       password prompt and use a custom one.
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("sudo -S -p '' "+command);
```

but when i run command like `"sudo -S -p - su bamboo"` still gives me the same error

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It worked for me

```
String command = "sudo su - bumboo";
channel.setPty(true);
```